# Is it possible to use an empty header value in HttpAddRequestHeaders()?

Tags: c++, windows, wininet

I am trying to use WinInet as an HTTP client, and some requests require empty headers, but various attempts at invocation always return parameter errors.

I haven't found any relevant instructions in the corresponding [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/Wininet/nf-wininet-httpaddrequestheadersa), but according to the HTTP RFC definitions, an empty header value should be valid. Therefore, I'm not sure whether it's because WinInet doesn't support it, or if there's an issue with the way I'm using it.

The related codes：

```
//***
if (!HttpAddRequestHeadersA(hRequest, "EmptyHeader01:\t\r\n",
    (ULONG)-1L, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD)) {
    std::cout << "HttpAddRequestHeadersA [EmptyHeader01:\t\r\n] failed with error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}


if (!HttpAddRequestHeadersA(hRequest, "EmptyHeader01:\r\n",
    (ULONG)-1L, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD)) {
    std::cout << "HttpAddRequestHeadersA [EmptyHeader01:\r\n] failed with error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}

if (!HttpAddRequestHeadersA(hRequest, "EmptyHeader01:",
    (ULONG)-1L, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD)) {
    std::cout << "HttpAddRequestHeadersA [EmptyHeader01:] failed with error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}

if (!HttpAddRequestHeadersA(hRequest, "EmptyHeader01: ",
    (ULONG)-1L, HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD)) {
    std::cout << "HttpAddRequestHeadersA [EmptyHeader01: ] failed with error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}
//***
```

Comment: One variation it doesn't look like you tried is `"EmptyHeader01: \r\n"`, i.e. Having the value be a space (to be stripped) and nothing else.

Comment: Disassembling the call and looking at the ReactOS implementation show that this simply isn't possible with this API.

Comment: > "EmptyHeader01: \r\n"
-----
this also not working.